# Data Mining small concept:Implicit and Explicit Data

Tags: data-mining

Is there any criteria for identifying if data is implicit or explicit in data mining
I know data must be explicit and non-trivial for data mining but how do you identify if data is implicit or explicit.Is it just by intuition?
Like for example,if Date of Birth is given and age is to be found it is implicit and trivial problem
But if DOB is given and average age is asked,it is explicit and non-trivial so how are we concluding whether data is implicit or explicit?

I thought it is by intuition but it seems complicated so please provide some insights which would bring in more clarity